# Angular 8: How to add days to the curent date

Tags: angular, validation

I have two date fields, invoiceDate and invoiceDueDate. On page initialisation, i set the invoiceDate to currentDate. I now need to set the invoiceDueDate to 30 days from the invoiveDate. With what I have now, am getting the error: getDate() is not a function, and I don't understand why?

On page initialisation, i set the invoiceDate to currentDate using my created helperService like this:

```html
invoice: InvoiceNew;
minDate: Date;

constructor(private helperService: HelperService) {
    this.invoice = new InvoiceNew(this.companyId);
}
ngOnInit() {
    // set invoiceDate to currentDate
    this.invoice.invoiceDate = this.helperService.getDateNewString;
    //  set invoiceDueDate to 30 days from the invoiceDate
    this.minDate = new Date();
    this.minDate.setDate(this.invoice.invoiceDate.getDate() + 30); 
}
```

Expected Output: if say invoiceDate is 01/10/2019,then invoiceDueDate should be 01/11/2019

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `setTime()`

```
let minDate = new Date();
minDate.setTime(minDate.getTime() + 1000*60*60*24*30);
```

Respectively;

1000 miliseconds = 1 seconds

60 seconds = 1 minute

60 minute = 1 hour

24 hour = 1 day

30 day = 1 month